# Good practice, pattern while implementing asynchronous 2d winforms elements

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, drawing, 2d

I would be grateful If somebody could advice me in following topic:

I prepared small Windows Forms game application which on main form has implemented following event in this way:

```
Shown += (sender, e) => GameItem.Start();
```

Suppose function Start() is responsible for drawing ball on form like that:

```
  while (true)
     {            
        game.BoardUI.pboxBall.Location = new Point(X++, Y++);
        game.BoardUI.pboxBall.Image = global::BoringGame.Properties.Resources.redBall;
         Application.DoEvents();
     }
```

main form has implemented another event:

```
MouseMove += (sender, e) => Game.MoveBoard(e.X);
```

this event is responsible for drawing board that ball colide and bounce from.
This event work asynchronously but the drawn board is blinking.

I would like to know how to implement event mouseMove so the drawn moving by mouse item is not blinking:

```
   public void MoveBoard(int x)
     { 
        new Thread(() =>
        {
           game.BoardUI.pboxPaddle.Location = new Point(X, Y);
            game.BoardUI.pboxPaddle.Image = global::BoringGame.Properties.Resources.ballPad;
        }).Start();                
    }
```

I tried to use `SynchronizationContext UiSyncContext;`

What should I do to improve my app.
Do I need separate thread to serve mouse move event? If yes, how to use it then?
Maybe drawing is not optimized - Maybe I should use another control to draw moving elements.
Currently I use picturebox.

I would be really grateful if someone advice me on that matter.

Thank for help, solution:

```
    //SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a timer that moves your image a fixed amount every interval of time.

Comment: It's best if you ask a specific question. Like "why is my game blinking?" If we have to read thirteen paragraphs before we get to the question many people will not try to help.

Comment: Do you have your form's DoubleBuffered property set to `true`?

Comment: Yes I set this property:  SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

Comment: Actually as I updated my question, not all form is blinking but the drawn item that is being moved by mouse event, addiotionally when I removed thread the moved object by mouse is blinking even more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blinking is the problem then you could try to minimize the time between when the moving object is erased and when it is redrawn in the new position. Threading probably will not help.  As itsme86 says it's probably a [buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) issue.

Comment: All right thank you very much I found solution: It was buffering indeed, I used this this.DoubleBuffered = true; instead of that: SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true); Thank you for your quick response. Best regards